# Multiple Subform field in module - add multiple items at once

Tags: subform, showon

I have a mutliple subform field with radio buttons. All other fields load by **showon** of the related parent radio select.

If there was added more than one item without saving successively, the radio buttons-state transferred to all items and the showon items are only merged to the first one.

This issue appears only by adding multiple items at once.

[image]

```
<field name="field-name" type="subform"
    formsource="modules/mod_myimage/forms/test1.xml" multiple="true"
label="Subform Field" description="Subform Field Description" />

//test1.xml
    <field name="myradiovalue" type="radio" default="0" label="Select an option" description="" class="btn-group btn-group-yesno">
        <option value="1">Heading</option>
        <option value="2">Content</option>
        <option value="3">Button</option>
        <option value="4">Image</option>
    </field>
```

It is clear why this happens without unique id before saving, but how to fix this?

```
<label for="jform_params__field_name__field_nameX__myradiovalue2" id="jform_params__field_name__**field_nameX**__myradiovalue2-lbl" class="btn">Button</label>
```

[image]

Comment: You XML doesn't appear to use the `showon` attribute

Comment: I added another picture. Found same issue here https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/10718#issuecomment-337209278

Comment: Seems this issue only appears at radio field, list field work fine for me.

Comment: May be an idea to post this as an issue on Joomla's Github Issue Tracker